# Retrofit First Service Response is Slow

Tags: android, http, https, retrofit2, android-webservice

I am Using Retrofit 2. The Issue I am facing is: The first response is coming late after eating up all the timeperiod mentioned in `connectTimeout`. And after the first call all the other webservice call runs taking no time.

Also, If I run it on the Wifi network it works without any issue, i.e The First Webservice runs and give response without giving any issue. But if I run it on Mobile/Device net(Internet provided by Service provider on the Mobile device) the response is again delivered after eating up all the time mentioned in the `connectTimeout`.

Below is my Retrofit API Class Code:-

```
public class APIClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request originalRequest = chain.request();

                    Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                            .header(Constants.KeyConstants.HEADER_AUTH, Constants.ConstantKeyTag.HEADER_AUTH_VALUE)
                            .header(Constants.KeyConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, Constants.ValuesConstant.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE) 
                            .method(originalRequest.method(), originalRequest.body())
                            .build();

                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });


            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.AppSpecificConstants.WS_BASEURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    final static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

}
```

I have refer the below links but has found nothing helpful:

[https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1489](http://github%20forum%20discussion%20link)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915469/retrofit-2-delayed-response](http://link%202)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034047/the-response-from-the-retrofit-call-is-too-slow-and-it-returns-a-null-list?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa](http://link%203:%20Stack%20overflow%20discussion%20on%20a%20bit%20similar%20issue)

Can anyone put the enlightment on the issue and any solution to resolve it.

Comment: I had an annoying android-only issue and eventually it was narrowed to using HTTP 1 vs 2 etc. You may want to create an iis or apache server just to see the logs

Comment: i'm having same issue.. did you find solution?

Comment: @RafaelLima Well In My case the issue was from server end. The server guy fixed the issue from his end and as a result my issue was resolved.